# How to get entire step name from @when and @Then annotations in Cucumber-JVM for custom test reports?

Tags: java, cucumber-jvm, gherkin

I need to create custom reports (Excel) in below format
Feature | Scenario | Step Name | Status | Test Data
Calculator | Add | When i add 2 and 4 | Passed | 2, 4
Calculator | Add | then 6 should be displayed | Passed | 6

In order to achieve this, i need fully qualified "Step Name" extracted from glued java step definitions @When and @Then. How to do that?

```
MyTest.feature

Feature: Calculator
Scenario: Add

Given that Calculator is ON  
When i add 2 and 4  
Then 6 should be displayed  

@When("^i add (\\d+)(.*) and (\\d+) (.*)$")  
public void calc_add(int a, int b){  
//code here  
//Need the entire string as i passed in .feature file
TestReport.log(stepName, assert(true));
}

@Then("^(\\d+) (.*) should be displayed$")  
public void calc_add(int c){  
//code here  
//Need the entire string as i passed in .feature file  
TestReport.log(stepName, assert(true));
}
```

Comment: You can create separate tag and in result , You click on tag and see entire result based on that.

Comment: @BostonStar, Can you please elaborate? Lets say i have created two tags as you suggested @ SetupReport and @ TearDown. How can i design flow to achieve what you suggested? I really dont understand on "You click on tag and see entire result based on that"

Comment: I am assuming you are running jenkins and jenkin plugin for cucumber result have result by tag. You can select tag and see all result from that tag.

Comment: I see that @ AfterStep and @ BeforeStep annotations have been added for this purpose. But waiting for sample code on how to extract the step names using these annotations. https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md